# Interaction between MaxKeepAliveRequests and MaxConnectionsPerChild

Tags: apache, keep-alive, amazon-elb

OK, this is on a series of very busy Apache 2.4 servers, using prefork MPM, behind AWS ELBs.  Because we are behind the ELBs it is foolish not to have keepalives on, however, we would like the child processes to regularly recycle.  Before turning on keepalives, the MaxConnectionsPerChild setting handled this.  But with keepalives, on there is essentially only one connection, so MaxConnectionsPerChild would be somewhat ineffective.  FWIW, the servers are too busy for KeepAliveTimeout or similar to ever kick in - they normally get several hundred requests per second, 24/7 with essentially no idle time.

Also, almost all requests are atomic with no subsequent requests for images, CSS, etc.  The real reason for the keep alive is because all the connections are from a single source, the load balancer.

So here is the issue...  We were thinking that in order to occasionally recycle the child processes, we could use settings like this:

```
KeepAlive               On
KeepAliveTimeout        20
MaxKeepAliveRequests    1500
MaxConnectionsPerChild  4
```

Again, the KeepAliveTimeout has basically no effect.  So the thinking is that with this setup, the persistent connection would be reset every 1500 requests, and then after 4 resets, the child would be recycled, i.e.; recycle the child process every 6000 requests.  However, this was causing the child processes to recycle about once a minute, which does not square with the level of traffic.  As a test, we changed the settings to:

```
KeepAlive               On
KeepAliveTimeout        20
MaxKeepAliveRequests    6000
MaxConnectionsPerChild  4
```

Expecting a four-fold increase in child lifetime.  However, the child processes are now cycling every 50 seconds to 2 minutes with no obvious pattern.

I am starting to think that these two settings do not interact as I thought they did.  Any insights into that?  And/or a "best practice" method to ensure occasional recycling of child processes in this situation?

Comment: did you have any luck figuring this out?

Comment: Nope.  And no responses here (obviously).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your KeepAlive is not active.

I can see on my Apache than when I set MaxKeepAliveRequests from 1500 to 6000, I  have a four-fold increase in child lifetime (with a constant requests rate).

- Are you sure that KeepAlive is active on the apache ? (by default : yes).
- Verify that the load balancer 'keepalive' is active.
- You should verify that the load balancer send HTTP 1.1 requests to apache (Keepalive connections are only supported as of HTTP/1.1). 
  You can see it in logs.